# How can I Collapse/Expand Multiple Divs in ngx-virtual-scroll?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngxs, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-byykpn

Here is what I have done so far, now I need to Expand/Collapse all divs which is after the group header.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap those divs in an `ng-container` with `ngIf` and toggle expansion.
I just considered you have a unique id for each item. So we can just use it to mark which item is expanded. In case you do not have a unique key for each item, you could just use the index of the item.

Your Template:

```
<button (click)="toggleExpand(item.id)">expand</button>

  <ng-container *ngIf="item.id == isExpanded">
          <div class="Question">Question1</div>
        <div class="Question">Question2</div>
        <div class="Question">Question3</div>
        <div class="Question">Question4</div>
        <div class="Question">Question5</div>
  </ng-container>
```

The toggle method:

```
toggleExpand(val) {
    this.isExpanded= val == this.isExpanded? '' : val;
  }
```

If you want to expand more than one row in the same time, then you should memorize the expanded rows in an object `isCollapsed` where the key is the expanded `item.id` and the value is a boolean e.g.

```
  isExpanded = {};

  toggleExpand(val) {
    this.isExpanded[val] = !this.isExpanded[val];
  }
```

And adjust your ng-container to:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isExpanded[item.name]">
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mehyar, But here I am using ngx-virtual-scroll and respect of it, and without adding ng-container can we do it? Thanks once again.

Comment: ng-container is a standard angular element and is not a bad idea to use it. 
But for sure you could replace the ng-container with a div and keep the ngIf on the div.
You should keep in mind that ng-container is useful in case you do not need to add another html element to the tree.

Comment: in my case, I am not able to differentiate question list, it like [{question1, group1}, {question2, group1},{question3, group2}.......{questionN, groupN} ]

Comment: Sorry I don not get what you mean. Could you explain

Comment: ok, so I want to say like the objects list what I am getting from API side is like  [{question1, group1}, {question2, group1},{question3, group2}.......{questionN, groupN} ] ,
that's why I am not able to make an ng-container for questions list for a particular group.

Comment: Could you update your post and your stackblitz explate to match what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239871/discussion-between-jay-khatri-and-mehyar-sawas).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-z6kuhs

Working example Thanks @Mehyar

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-wh7oof here is similier examle where i got some zigzak while use virtualscroll.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have a *boolean* array for mapping collapsed divs.

See your code working [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-nzqnbw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-nzqnbw?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
isCollapsed: boolean[] = [];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      this.items.push({ name: 'Item ' + i });
      this.isCollapsed[i] = true;
    }

    // Just to see the first item not collapsed, you can omit it if you want them all collapsed by default.
       if (this.items.length > 0) { this.isCollapsed[0] = false; }
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div
        *ngFor="let item of scroll.viewPortItems; let indexOfColaps = index"
        class="groupQuestion"
      >

<div *ngIf="!isCollapsed[indexOfColaps]">
          <div class="Question">Question1</div>
          <div class="Question">Question2</div>
          <div class="Question">Question3</div>
          <div class="Question">Question4</div>
          <div class="Question">Question5</div>
</div>

\\You can change div *ngIf="... for container *ngIf="... if you want.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I have update stackBlits https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-pzybnr 

please ignore *ngIf="!(indexOfColaps % 5)" it will be add by dynamic.

Comment: ok, so for these new changes, here you got your working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-e5krdz?file=src/app/app.component.html In order to simplify it, I needed to add 2 new fields to item object,  groupNumber:number and showQuestion:boolean

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-wh7oof 

please check this and expand the first group and scroll to the end

Comment: Sorry but this last url you have provided, doesn't work (It doesn't fully load the web, stays with the spinner forever...showing the message "Starting dev server"...)

Comment: its work from my side : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-virtual-scroller-wh7oof